# 500 error response to CORS preflight OPTIONS when calling cloud function. How can I call a cloud function from my web-app and be CORS compliant?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, preflight

**I'm trying to incorporate cloud functions into my web-app.**
Unfortunately I'm getting CORS errors that I'm struggling to handle.
It seems that pretty much all of the documentation re CORS is using XMLHTTPRequests and some are using the fetch api, but I can't find any info on how to do it with `firebase.functions.httpsCallabe()`

Client code:

```
export function bla() {
const callable = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('helloWorld');
    return callable().then(console.log);
}
```

The entire cloud function (It's in typescript):

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        response.status(200).send("Hello from Firebase!");
    });
});
```

This is what the chrome console outputs upon triggering my `bla()` function:
[image: Screenshot of the console output]

In the Firebase console I'm getting a message that I'm using the standard plan and that I therefore can't access outside sources. Not sure if this is the standard message or an actual problem with my code.

Comment: Notice that https://i.imgur.com/pHr9NQO.png indicates your browser is making a CORS preflight OPTIONS request and the server is responding to that OPTIONS request with a 500 error. That 500 error is the root problem you need to fix.

Comment: It looks like you have not properly configured the server to accept CORS. https://enable-cors.org/ the server need to respond to the options call with access control headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the Functions client SDK to invoke [HTTP type functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  You can only use the Functions client SDK to invoke [callable type functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that are declared as you see in the linked documentation.

Callable functions are declared using `functions.https.onCall`, while HTTP functions are declared using `functions.https.onRequest`.

If you want to invoke a normal HTTP type function, you should use some HTTP client for that.

Comment: Does it not look like CORS is not enabled on that server?

Comment: @JuanMendes It doesn't matter.  It just won't work.  The client won't even be invoking the URL for that function.  The Functions SDK will take over every detail of the HTTP transaction.

Comment: Ah, nice, that worked! Best thing is that I won't even have to deal with Auth manually that way. I guess the fact that it was labelled as "App" in the reference mislead me into believing that it's not for Web.

Comment: If you find something confusing in the documentation, please use the "send feedback" link at the top of every page.